# Enabling/Disabling database connection on the basis of active profile or yml property value

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I want my application to stop loading the database connection when launched in local environment and use Couchbase database when launched in Dev environment. So to start with it I have excluded *CouchbaseDataAutoConfiguration* -

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude= {CouchbaseDataAutoConfiguration.class})
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy()
public class ABCAdapterApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ABCAdapterApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

And commented out the *@Configuration* from the *AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration* class

```
//@Configuration
public class ABCAdapterBucketConnection extends AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration{
        /* buckets configuration here*/
}
```

After this I can see in the logs that Spring is not loading any database connection but it gives org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException -

```
{"timestamp":"2020-05-09 15:31:37.073","severity":"WARN","class":"org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext","crId":"","msg":"Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'ABCAdapterRetrySourceRoute': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dataProcessor'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'persistDataProcessor': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.vu.payments.abc.adapter.repositories.KafkaPayloadRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.}
```

Why the classes with @Repository annotation were not registered in Spring context when I had disabled couchbase auto-configuration ? How can I stop this application from failing to start-up even if there is no database connection when launched in local environment ?

Comment: `ABCAdapterRetrySourceRoute` might have some dependency on `ABCAdapterBucketConnection`.

Comment: On a side note, why do you want to achieve this? If the code has a dependency on a database, it should fail. How will the code accessing the Couchbase work on local?

Comment: you can inject 'KafkaPayloadRepository' indirectly - from Spring application context, then put conditional logic on presence.

Answer (score 0):

There is a handler class which based on active profile instantiates a data loader class (**FromFile** or **FromDatabase** both implementing **ConfigLoader** i/f). When no profile is selected **FromFile** gets instantiated and this class makes no reference to any repository class or method that's why It should work even if database has not been loaded. I looked thoroughly and found that **KafkaPayloadRepository** is being referred directly in **PersistDataProcessor**. Direct reference to repository classes has to be avoided in this use case and **ConfigLoader** interface should be used instead.